# How to delete only row that is assigned to that value? (Don't know how to write it in title)

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to make post system. 
Everything is working perfectly, but there is one thing I can't figure out...
I have some rows in database that I pulled out with prepared mysqli. Well, when I echo the value of rows, it shows the correct echo, and it shows all the columns (that's what if should obviously do) and that's good.
SQL :

```
SELECT id,postby,downvotes,upvotes FROM posts
```

and binding result like this:

```
bind_result($postid,$postby,$downvotes,$upvotes);
```

So it's working. They are all pulled out on echo. That's good.

BUT! When I'm trying to delete any row (only one) from that table with result from prepared mysqli, it deletes ALL the rows...
My code for deleting the row :

```
DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ?
```

and binded parameter like

```
bind_param('i',$postid);
```

But this deletes ALL rows in database. I want it to delete only the one that is assigned to the id. So if it pull out 20 rows from DB, it will delete all the rows in DB... How can I delete only one row that is assigned to it's id?
Thanks!

I have to mention that I already tried something like `<input name='deletesomething' type='hidden' value='<php? echo $postid ?>'>` and then with something like

```
bind_param('s',$_POST['deletesomething']);
```

But it still deletes all the rows. How this could be fixed?

**EDIT**

Sorry! Actually the method with hidden input works, but it's very unsafe because user can change the value and it will delete different row...

**EDIT 2**

My full code to understand what I actually want to do.

```
<?php
$selectposts = "SELECT postby,posttxt,time,upvotes,downvotes,id FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($selectposts);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($postby,$posttxt,$posttime,$upvotesdb,$downvotesdb,$postid);
$stmt->store_result();
while($stmt->fetch()){
   $picturestmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT picture FROM members WHERE username = ?");
        $picturestmt->bind_param('s', $postby);
        $picturestmt->execute();
        $picturestmt->bind_result($picture);
                        while($picturestmt->fetch()){
                                if(empty($picture)){
                                        $profpicturefromdb = " <img src='profile_pictures/public_icon.png' width='25' height='25' class='fxdmimg'>";
                                } else {
                                        $profpicturefromdb = " <img width='25' class='fxdmimg' height='25' src='profile_pictures/".$picture."' alt='Profile Picture'>";
                                }
                        }


echo 
"<p><center><div class='postdv'> 
<b>".$profpicturefromdb." 
<a href='http://www.fregbind.16mb.com/".$postby.".php'><h3>".$postby."</h3></a></b><font color='#000'>  
[ ".$posttime." ] </font>"; 
if($_SESSION['username'] == $postby){
     echo"<label for='pedform'><img src='pictures/ped.png' rel='icon' width='15' height='15' class='icnimg'></label>
     <label for='xdelform'><img src='pictures/xdel.png' rel='icon' width='15' height='15' class='icnimg'></label>
     <div class='hidden'><form method='POST'><input id='pedform' type='submit'></form> 
     <form method='POST'><input type='submit' id='xdelform'></form></div>";
     } 
     echo "<hr class='hrgray'><br>
<font color='#000'>".$posttxt."</font><p>";

$votestmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT upvotes, downvotes FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
$votestmt->bind_param('i',$postid);
$votestmt->execute();
$votestmt->bind_result($upvotes,$downvotes);
$votestmt->store_result();
while($votestmt->fetch()){

if(isset($_POST['voteup'])){
    echo $postid;
$onevalue = "1";
$makeitplusone = $upvotes + $onevalue;

$addvote = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE posts SET upvotes = ? WHERE id = ?");
$addvote->bind_param('si',$makeitplusone,$postid);
$addvote->execute();

}
echo"<form method='POST'><input type='submit' name='voteup' class='voteup' value='Up'><font color='#00CC00'> ".$upvotes." </font>
    <input type='submit' name='votedown' class='votedown' value='Down'> <font color='#FF4747'>".$downvotes." </font>
    </form>
    </center>
    </div>";
}
}

?>
```

Here is a slightly different code. Not much different but this just have to change the value of upvote to +1 when it's clicked, however it updates ALL rows to +1...

**EDIT 3**

We are talking about this part:

```
$votestmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT upvotes, downvotes FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
$votestmt->bind_param('i',$postid);
$votestmt->execute();
$votestmt->bind_result($upvotes,$downvotes);
$votestmt->store_result();
while($votestmt->fetch()){

if(isset($_POST['voteup'])){
    echo $postid;
$onevalue = "1";
$makeitplusone = $upvotes + $onevalue;

$addvote = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE posts SET upvotes = ? WHERE id = ?");
$addvote->bind_param('si',$makeitplusone,$postid);
$addvote->execute();

}
echo"<form method='POST'><input type='submit' name='voteup' class='voteup' value='Up'><font color='#00CC00'> ".$upvotes." </font>
    <input type='submit' name='votedown' class='votedown' value='Down'> <font color='#FF4747'>".$downvotes." </font>
    </form>
```

Comment: where are you getting your id from. Can you please add more code?

Comment: Is that delete in a loop? Can you post your full code?

Comment: It's written in my question. I'm getting it with prepared selection as shown up↑

Comment: @chris85 - Yes it is in while because I want it to pull out all rows from database

Comment: Take it out of the while, that's why it is deleting every record... presuming your `$postid` = the return from the fetch. Having not seen all your code I don't know though.

Comment: @chris85 - but how can I pull out all rows from db?

Comment: Run your select, store the data, then run the delete for the one you want to delete.

Comment: @chris85 - but this means that I have to assign it manually. I'll post my full code rather... check edit 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76572/discussion-between-chris85-and-steven-tomko).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what this code is doing but try this (lines 38 and 49 are the modifications)...

```
<?php
$selectposts = "SELECT postby,posttxt,time,upvotes,downvotes,id FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($selectposts);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($postby,$posttxt,$posttime,$upvotesdb,$downvotesdb,$postid);
$stmt->store_result();
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $picturestmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT picture FROM members WHERE username = ?");
    $picturestmt->bind_param('s', $postby);
    $picturestmt->execute();
    $picturestmt->bind_result($picture);
    while($picturestmt->fetch()){
        if(empty($picture)){
            $profpicturefromdb = " <img src='profile_pictures/public_icon.png' width='25' height='25' class='fxdmimg'>";
        } else {
            $profpicturefromdb = " <img width='25' class='fxdmimg' height='25' src='profile_pictures/".$picture."' alt='Profile Picture'>";
        }
    }
    echo 
    "<p><center><div class='postdv'> 
    <b>".$profpicturefromdb." 
    <a href='http://www.fregbind.16mb.com/".$postby.".php'><h3>".$postby."</h3></a></b><font color='#000'>  
    [ ".$posttime." ] </font>"; 
    if($_SESSION['username'] == $postby){
        echo"<label for='pedform'><img src='pictures/ped.png' rel='icon' width='15' height='15' class='icnimg'></label>
        <label for='xdelform'><img src='pictures/xdel.png' rel='icon' width='15' height='15' class='icnimg'></label>
        <div class='hidden'><form method='POST'><input id='pedform' type='submit'></form> 
        <form method='POST'><input type='submit' id='xdelform'></form></div>";
        } 
        echo "<hr class='hrgray'><br>
    <font color='#000'>".$posttxt."</font><p>";
        if($_POST['upvoteid'] == $postid && isset($_POST['voteup'])){
            echo 'This:' . $_POST['upvoteid'] . ':equals:' . $postid . '.';
            $addvote = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE posts SET upvotes = upvotes + 1 WHERE id = ?");
            $addvote->bind_param('i',$postid);
            $addvote->execute();
        }
        echo"<form method='POST'>
                <input type='submit' name='voteup' class='voteup' value='Up'><font color='#00CC00'> ".$upvotes." </font>
                    <input type='submit' name='votedown' class='votedown' value='Down'> <font color='#FF4747'>".$downvotes." </font>
                <input name='upvoteid' type='hidden' value='$postid'>
                </form>
                </center>
            </div>";
    }
}
?>
```

This way you only run the update for the one that was submitted. Previously you were checking if a field is set which would be set for every one of these records.

Comment: Well but name is different so it would be $_POST['voteup'] and $_POST['votedown'] value

Comment: Like I said I don't know exactly what you're trying to do but this will make it so it only increases the 1 record.

Comment: Well I know what you mean but that's not it. You think that I mean that the value is +1 for upvotes and downvotes right? Well no... The value is changed only for upvotes as clicked on submit button. That is good, but it changes the value to ALL rows , so if you click on vote up on any post, it will +1 to all posts that exist.

Comment: This line `if(isset($_POST['voteup']) && $_POST['upvoteid'] == $postid){` requires the submitted record is a vote up and that it is for the particular record in question if it is it increases, if not it won't update. That field is being populated here `<input name='upvoteid' type='hidden' value='$postid'>`. You will need a separate check for `POST['votedown']` or you could make it one submit and have the down/up be the value...

Comment: yeh that's it but this is very unsafe because when somebody would change the value through F12 , it would update as of the value he wrote. That's why I'm asking for such a help because I found this solution as unsafe. Just try to imagine that he would change the value from your post's id to his post's id, so he'll get another +1 on his post through "your" post...:/

Comment: Okay, than your questions was quite unclear in that case. Your question is not `How to delete only row that is assigned to that value?`. You could do this by setting users to certain levels with different permissions or by requiring users be logged in. Look at how this site does it. You cant upvote your own post, it just checks the logged in user and denies upvote of the questions asked by that userid.

Comment: but this is actually only for users that are logged in. I mean that if you click that button "upvote" it should make the post's upvotes +1.. but only the post's upvotes you clicked. But when you click the upvote for that post, it upvotes all the posts in database. That's the deal. I want to update only one row, not all.. same as you like status on facebook, when you click on like button, you like only that one current status, not all statuses that exists... understand? :D

Comment: Yes. It still updates all rows in the DB...And I don't even know why, because when I echo postid , it shows an ID of the post, and the id is different for each post obviously... So when I see there 20 posts, there are 20 different ID's... so I don't know why it is not working...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76577/discussion-between-chris85-and-steven-tomko).